# $L^2(\mathbb R, \mu) $ a finite dimensional space.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Hi I find the following exercise. Honestly I'm not sure about my "answer", is incredible simple.t I don't know if make sense (in what part is necessary to use $L^2$?). I'd appreciate if someone can clarify the ideas of the exercise.Thank you

> Prove that if a measure $\mu$, defined on $\mathscr B (\mathbb R)$ it has a finite number of increasing points, then $ L^2 $ is a finite dimensional space.

I'm not sure of this, but my idea is as follows. Let $K=\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ the support of $\mu$. Let $f$ in $ L^2 (\mathbb R)$, so $f(x) = \sum_{1\le k \le n} f(c_k) \chi_{c_k} (x)$ holds a.e.-$\mu$. Thus for each $f$ in $L^2$ it can be written as a linear combination of $\{\chi_{c_k}: 1\le k \le n\}$ so is a base to $L^2$ an so is finite dimensional space.

Comment: sounds good to me. You are using the fact that two elements of $L^2$ are identified when they are equal $\mu$-almost everywhere and it might be worth saying this explicitly. Also, the title of this question is odd because most people would not write $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (without reference to the measure on $\mathbb{R}$) for any measure but Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @hunter thank you. So the use of $L^2 (\mathbb R, \mu)$ is completely unnecesary. Basically the same argument works for any finite $p$, right?

Comment: I agree -- 2 can be replaced by anything

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the attempt is good. Furthermore, the argument works for $\mathbb L^p$ where $1\leqslant p<+\infty$.